# Adding text to TextView inside inflator

Tags: android, textview, layout-inflater

I got my inflator to show the amount of rows that I want.  I am having trouble inserting text into each textview inside the inflator.  It only populated the first TextView and leaves the rest blank. I tried using arrays but kept getting a run time error

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfGuests; ++i) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_per_person, table);
            float numberInsertedForPerson = (float) (Math.round(tipPerPersons * 100.0) / 100.0);
            String sTipPerPerson = Float.toString(numberInsertedForPerson);
            tipPerPerson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipPerPerson);
            tipPerPerson.setText(sTipPerPerson);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is the (in my opinion) quite confusing behavior of `LayoutInflater`.

Firstly, you should cache a reference instead of getting the `LayoutInflater` on every iteration. Secondly, when you call the `inflate(int, ViewGroup)` method, it actually returns the second parameter (the `ViewGroup`), *not* the inflated `View`. The answer to this is to pass in a third parameter (whether or not the `View` should be attached) as false. This will give you the inflated `View`, which you can then attach to the parent `ViewGroup`. The correct way would look like this:

```
LayoutInflater in = getLayoutInflater();

for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfGuests; i++) {
    View v = in.inflate(R.layout.row_per_person, table, false);
    float num = (float) (Math.round(tipPerPersons * 100.0) / 100.0);
    String tip = Float.toString(num);
    tipPerPerson = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tipPerPerson);
    tipPerPerson.setText(tip);
    table.addView(v);
}
```

Comment: It works, I just forgot to mention another fact about that which is when you pass false, it does not get added to the parent `ViewGroup`. Check my recent edit -- you need to call `addView()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, its my first android project in a year and a half and I don't remember a lot of it and don't use java at work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using findViewById, you should add view.findViewById